# Would Parse be executed after Fetch finished if fetcher.parse is set to true, using Nutch?

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I want to parse web page content roughly in phase **Fetch** and subtly in phase **Parse**. What should I do? Would Parse be executed after Fetch finished if `fetcher.parse` is set to `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse phase will be executed after Fetch phase anyway, it doesn't matter if you set `fetcher.parse` to False or True. Only thing you should notice is that when you set it to True, the crawling will be safer, parsing issues don't lead to a loss of the fetched content.

Please have a look on this:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-872